# Issues with javac-algs4 compiler

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to use Princeton Course specific Java Compiler (javac-algs4) on my windows machine and am seeing this error:

$ javac-algs4
warning: [path] bad path element "/usr/local/lift/lib/algs4.jar": no such file or directory
javac: no source files

This is related to Princeton Algorithms 1 Course. I followed the instructions on installing IntelliJ Idea from https://lift.cs.princeton.edu/java/windows/ and other steps to configure CLASSPATH.

javac and java work ok on HelloWorld programs, but I am expecting javac-algs4 to work for programs that use Course specific libraries. 
It seems to me like a Unix Path may be hidden in the JAR file that I`m using in the CLASSPATH, and that may be breaking things for me. (Notice the /usr/local... directory in my error)

What steps could I take to troubleshoot and resolve the error?

Other Version Info: 
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
Javac Version: javac 10.0.2

Comment: The file `/usr/local/lift/lib/algs4.jar` does not exist. And questions with university specific tools should really be direct to your lecturer or student assistant / tutor.

Comment: I`m on a Windows machine. Should the Unix dir in my error still matter?